# Как добавить кнопку в основное оконное меню?

Tags: qt, menu, qml, qtquick

Есть ли какой  то способ в QML добавить кнопку в основное оконное меню (то, где кнопки свернуть-закрыть-переместить окно, собственно рядом с ними)

UPD: 
Подойдут также любые решения по отрисовке новой панели.  Главное условие: получившаяся панель должна выглядеть как основная панель окна. То есть при смене темы windows должа принимать вид этой темы (в том числе прозрачный)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убирать стандартные кнопки гораздо проще, чем их добавлять (см. [пример](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html)). А вот с добавлением своих новых элементов всё непросто.

Сразу обратим внимание, что приложение делается только под Windows (судя по тексту вопроса). Ничего специального в Qt для поддержки этих кнопок я не знаю, поэтому придётся погружаться в WIN API. До эпохи Aero задача решалась легко - мы могли самостоятельно рисовать что угодно: просто ловим `WM_NCPAINT` ([перерисовку вне клиентской области](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx)), реагируем на события заголовка окна (`WM_NCHITTEST`, `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` и т.д).

Это примерно как обработка `WM_PAINT`, только рисуем не внутри окна, а во всём окне.

А вот с начала эпохи визуальных схем всё стало гораздо сложнее. Насколько я понимаю, единственный нормальный способ - это своими ручками повторить стили рисования кнопок. То есть, в своём коде надо посмотреть, какая версия Windows у пользователя и включена ли Aero, чтобы выбрать, какой ширины рамочки использовать и т.д. Подход плохой (буду рад, если кто-то укажет более человеческое решение), поэтому лучше трезво подумать, точно ли надо добавлять новые кнопки.

Но поскольку заниматься этим никто не хочет, то обычно просто игнорируют стили Windows (например, Google Chrome использует полностью свой стиль окон, поэтому смело пихает какие хочет кнопки в любые части заголовка окна).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: А что вы скажете по этому поводу, должно раюотать? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Да, так можно рисовать заголовок окна (ну и вообще всю рамку). Но проблема та же: стиль кнопки придётся выдумывать самостоятельно (или пытаться повторить стиль текущей версии операционной системы).

Comment: Добавлю после попыток применить "расширить рамку на клиентскую область" - работает это только применительно к aero. Если Aero отключен - рамка остается на месте

Comment: Странно. Создавайте ещё один вопрос со своим кодом - поглядим.

Comment: К сожалению спрашивать исправлять тут нечего - это документированная фича http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-quickplayer-example.html вот тут пример (и у меня тот же самый ). А вот если вы в QML вообще разбираетесь - можете помочь мне ответить на этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465445/qml-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0